Machine learning input with numerical columns and array columns, handling mixed-type data in machine learning
I am working on a machine learning project where I have a dataset with a combination of numeric columns and columns containing arrays. The numeric columns (eg. Mean) contain single values, while the columns with arrays (eg. Gradient) can have a variable number of elements per row.
What are the best practices for dealing with this type of input? Can I use numeric columns and columns with arrays simultaneously in a machine learning model? If so, what are the most common strategies to handle this heterogeneity of data during the preprocessing and training phase of the model?
I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or resources that can help me better understand how to deal with this challenge.
Example:
Input of the model:



Mean
Gradient




0.5
[1,2,3,45,0.2]


1
[2,5,1.2,5,0]




I am sorry, but it is absolutely not possible to use numeric and array inputs simultaneously in a machine learning model.
